# Laravel 9 - Can't init variables in component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a component that works in local, but not on a server (Forge/aws). The problem is that it does not find the variable $idiomasc (Undefined variable $idiomasc).

Component code:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use App\Models\Idioma;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Textosck extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

     public $idiomasc;
     public $tipo;
     public $textos;
 
    public function __construct($tipo, $textos = [])
    {
        $this->tipo = $tipo;
        $this->idiomasc = 'Hello';
        $this->textos = $textos;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.textosck');
    }

}
```

textosck View:

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab-{{$tipo}}" role="tablist">
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">    
        {{ $idiomasc }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And init in some blade with:

```
<x-textosck tipo="descripcionEspacio" :textos="$translations['descripcion_espacio']"/>
```

Tests carried out without result:

- Initialize the variable as an empty string.
- Add Blade::component(Textosck::class, 'Textosck'); in the register(), inside the appSeviceProvider class
- Pass the variable to the constructor
- Change the name of the variable
- Clear all types of cache on the server (laravel caches, and composer dump-autoload)
- Delete the variable (Everything works fine, the variable $tipo is displayed correctly)
- I have tried to create a new component, copy all the code and upload it to the server, same error

Comment: You need to add props in your textosck component https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components

Comment: Yes, I finally did this. But I didn't understand why it works on localhost, but nope on the server :(